# Defining a class with composition relationship

Tags: c++

A document can have many containers and each container may or may not have sub-containers. Each container has name and container id.

In C++ I have modeled it as follows

```
 class Container
    {
        string ContainerName;
        int ContainerID;

        int NumberofSubContainers; //number of sub-containers this contain contains
        Container* subcontainerlist;
    };

    class Document
    {
        string DocumentName;

        int NumofContainers; //number of containers document contains
        Container* containerlist;
    };
```

Is this approach correct or can there be a better alternative ?

Comment: Just so you know, it is common practice for classes only to be named with UpperCase, and for variables and instances to be named using camelCase. Just a formatting difference. If you notice with SO's syntax highlighting, the UpperCase variable names are a different color than the camelCase ones.

Comment: I have also seen members and methods written as `lowercase_with_underscores`; the C++ standard library is fond of this style. Personally, I use the convention C0deH4cker describes because that sets user code apart from standard library code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use the containers provided by STL rather than describing your own (unless you have proven it to be unsuitable). If the (sub)containers are ordered, but not sorted by their ID, then a `vector` or `deque` would probably be good choices. All STL containers have a `size()` method that reports the number of elements held by the container.

You also did not make any of your members public in your model. You will either need to make them public, or provide public accessors, or define friends. As a model, you should probably define public interfaces, so that you will be free to modify your implementation later while leaving your model intact.

In your model, `Document` looks exactly like a `Container` except for the ID, so it could be factored out.

```
class Container;
typedef std::vector<Container> Containers;

class ContainerOwner
{
protected:
    std::string m_name;
    Containers m_list;
};

class Document : public ContainerOwner
{
public:
    std::string & DocumentName () { return m_name; }
    const std::string & DocumentName () const { return m_name; }

    Containers & ContainerList () { return m_list; }
    const Containers & ContainerList () const { return m_list; }
};

class Container : public ContainerOwner
{
    int m_id;
public:
    std::string & ContainerName () { return m_name; }
    const std::string & ContainerName () const { return m_name; }

    int & ContainerId () { return m_id; }
    int ContainerId () const { return m_id; }

    Containers & SubContainerList () { return m_list; }
    const Containers & SubContainerList () const { return m_list; }
};
```

Comment: I'd rename `DocumentBase` to `ContainerOwner` or something similar. It's kind of odd saying "a container *is a* document base."

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, thanks for the suggestion. Edit has been made.